# How to get the nth row in HBase with java?

Tags: indexing, row, hbase

I have a big table in which I'd like to get the nth row.
I've seen that putting an integer index at the beginning of the rowkey is a bad idea because of hbase data managing system...

So instead of :

```
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Get getRow=new org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Get(rowKey);
```

I'd like to do something like :

```
Get getRowByIndex=Get(int IndexOfWantedRow);
```

Is there any existing method ?
Thank you !

Comment: What's your use case?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question following are different probable solutions

**1. Integer is the rowKey**

Looking at your access pattern, you want to access data based on the rowNumber. Why not have the rowNumber as rowKey in that case? You can directly use Get api to get the nth row.

**2. Prefix Integer to rowkey**

You can prefix the rowKey with the rowNumber and then access the data through Scan api to get the data.
eg : rowKey Generated - N_customRowKey
Scan command - scan ("N_")

To handle hotspot issue due to sequential numbers, you can use hash(N) instead of N in both options.
But in that case it will be very difficult to use the scan api for your actual rowKey.